# Displaying User custom field in wordpress (ACF)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I made a custom field in User. I want to show some details of the user. The fields are displaying in Users but if I write some content and call the field with this method:

```php
the_field('user_description');
```

It is not displaying the content in the author archive page. Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

For user options you'll need to use a second argument for the `the_field`. The second argument need to start with `user_` and end with the user ID. So, to retrieve an option from the current user, you'll do like this:

```
?php the_field('field_name', 'user_' . get_current_user_id()); ?>
```